# XGBoost model quantization - Sklearn model quantization

Tags: python, scikit-learn, onnx, quantization

I am looking for solutions to quantize sklearn models. I am specifically looking for XGBoost models.

I did find solutions to quantize pytorch and tensorflow models but nothing on sklearn.

Solutions tried:

Converted sklearn model to ONNX and then tried to quantize ONNX model, but that didn't work either. Here is the link to the [bug](https://github.com/onnx/sklearn-onnx/issues/816).

Any pointers or solutions can be shared, it would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Someone had answered the question in your link [bug](https://github.com/onnx/sklearn-onnx/issues/816).

Try not to add a final node ZipMap by the 'zipmap' option:

```
onx = convert_sklearn(clr, initial_types=initial_type,
                      options={'zipmap': False})
```

I'm interested to know if that works for you?

BTW, you can use onnxmltools to convert a XGBoost model to ONNX according to [this](https://www.modelconverter.qeexo.com/userguide.html#xgboost-models).

the sample code:

```
import onnx
import onnxmltools
from onnxmltools.convert.common.data_types import FloatTensorType
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

clf = XGBClassifier()

# fit the classifier...

onnx_model_path = "xgb_classifier.onnx"
initial_type = [('float_input', FloatTensorType([None, num_features]))]
onnx_model = onnxmltools.convert.convert_xgboost(clf, initial_types=initial_type, target_opset=10)
onnx.save(onnx_model, onnx_model_path)
```

Note that:

- Model must be trained using the scikit-learn API of xgboost
- The training data passed to XGBClassifier().fit() must not have feature names associated with it. For example, if your training data is a DataFrame called df, which has column names, you will need to use a representation without column names (i.e. df.values) when training.